# Compare IP address to IPv6 block

Tags: php, ip, ipv6

I'm using PHP to compare the user IP address to a list of IP blocks, most of which are IPv4 but some of them are IPv6. The IP address I get from the user is always IPv4 compatible, or so I'm assuming. How would I go about comparing this?

This is what I'm using now:

```
function ip_check($ip, $cidr) {
  list($net, $mask) = split("/", $cidr);
  $ip_address = decbin(ip2long($ip));
  $ip_net = decbin(ip2long($net));
  if (substr($ip_net, 0, $mask) == substr($ip_address, 0, $mask)) {
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Edit: As an example I need to see if **194.144.247.254** belongs to **2001:067c:006c::/48** or **2001:1a98::/32** or **217.151.176.18/32** or **217.171.208.0/20**.

Answer (score 3):

I've written [a library to do this sort of IP address comparison](https://github.com/leth/PHP-IPAddress/).

```
$ip = IP_Address::factory($ip);
$block = IP_Network_Address::factory($cidr);

return $block->encloses_address($ip);
```

The class hierarchy is a bit obtuse because it's designed to enable Kohana's transparent extension.

I've not implemented the code to convert an IPv4 address to a special previxed IPv6 address, so you may have to do a small amount of checking before the comparison.
Pull requests are of course welcomed :)

Comment: That's awesome but unfortunately I can't install the PEAR Math_BigInteger class in this case.

Comment: License restrictions, or just server rights? You can always download the class and include it in your app manually. IIRC IPv4 stuff will work fine without that class.

Comment: Server. I might just try downloading the class.

Comment: Actually, for what you're doing, it probably won't need the PEAR class at all.

Answer (score 0):

> As an example I need to see if **194.144.247.254** belongs to
>   **2001:067c:006c::/48** or **2001:1a98::/32** or **217.151.176.18/32** or
>   **217.171.208.0/20**.

How can a IPv4 address belong to a IPv6 range? You can only compare the same kind of addresses this way. The other thing makes no sense.

Comment: The IPv6 address is IPv4 compatible and is returned as xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx