# How to check an IP address is within a range of two IPs in PHP? - with ipv6 support

Tags: php, ip, ipv6

This is essentially a duplicate of this question: [How to check an IP address is within a range of two IPs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121817/how-to-check-an-ip-address-is-within-a-range-of-two-ips-in-php)

However the solution to the above question does not support ipv6.  Is there a similar solution with ipv6 support?

Comment: what about this http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ip2long.php#104163 ?

Comment: +1 for point out to comments part of php manual, It always have some kind solution of any limitations of function.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8836083/175849

Answer (score 2):

#### Suggestions:

```
string inet_ntop ( string $in_addr )
```

> This function converts a 32bit IPv4, or 128bit IPv6 address (if PHP
>   was built with IPv6 support enabled) into an address family
>   appropriate string representation.

You should also see,

```
string inet_pton ( string $address )
```

#### inet_ntop() Example

```
<?php
$packed = chr(127) . chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(1);
$expanded = inet_ntop($packed);

/* Outputs: 127.0.0.1 */
echo $expanded;

$packed = str_repeat(chr(0), 15) . chr(1);
$expanded = inet_ntop($packed);

/* Outputs: ::1 */
echo $expanded;
?>
```

#### Comparing in range

The following two functions were introduced in PHP 5.1.0, `inet_pton` and `inet_pton`. Their purpose is to convert human readable IP addresses into their packed `in_addr` representation. Since the result is not pure binary, we need to use the `unpack` function in order to apply bitwise operators.

Both functions support IPv6 as well as IPv4. The only difference is how you unpack the address from the results. With IPv6, you will unpack with contents with A16, and with IPv4, you will unpack with A4.

To put the previous in a perspective here is a little sample output to help clarify:

```
// Our Example IP's
$ip4= "10.22.99.129";
$ip6= "fe80:1:2:3:a:bad:1dea:dad";


// ip2long examples
var_dump( ip2long($ip4) ); // int(169239425)
var_dump( ip2long($ip6) ); // bool(false)


// inet_pton examples
var_dump( inet_pton( $ip4 ) ); // string(4)
var_dump( inet_pton( $ip6 ) ); // string(16)
```

We demonstrate above that the inet_* family supports both IPv6 and v4. Our next step will be to translate the packed result into an unpacked variable.

```
// Unpacking and Packing
$_u4 = current( unpack( "A4", inet_pton( $ip4 ) ) );
var_dump( inet_ntop( pack( "A4", $_u4 ) ) ); // string(12) "10.22.99.129"


$_u6 = current( unpack( "A16", inet_pton( $ip6 ) ) );
var_dump( inet_ntop( pack( "A16", $_u6 ) ) ); //string(25) "fe80:1:2:3:a:bad:1dea:dad"
```

Note : The current function returns the first index of an array. It is equivelant to saying $array[0].

After the unpacking and packing, we can see we achieved the same result as input. This is a simple proof of concept to ensure we are not losing any data.

Finally use,

```
if ($ip <= $high_ip && $low_ip <= $ip) {
  echo "in range";
}
```

Reference: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-ntop.php)